# sql dev query moving multiple rows to many columns

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am very new to sql dev and have a query with results below...

```
TeacherID   TFirstName  TLastName   StudentID   SFirstName  SLastName
11113       Doe         John        12345       Jane1       Doe1
11113       Doe         John        12346       Jane2       Doe2
11113       Doe         John        12347       Jane3       Doe3
```

I get many rows of one teacher with all their students in rows.
I want one teacher with all the students in columns.

```
Teacherid  tfirstname  tlastname  studentid  sfirstname  slastname  studentid sfirstname  slastname  studentid  sfirstname  slastname      
11113      Doe         John       12345      Jane1       Doe1       12346     Jane2       Doe2       12347      Jane3       Doe3
```

and so on for the 20 students in this class.

Is this possible?  Like I said I am new to sql dev.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Do you want header rows to be teacher details and the other rows to be students details? The table for your result is so misleading.

Comment: Tag your question properly!!!  The syntax is different for different dbms.  It's useless if we give you solution to the wrong dbms.  It's wasting everybody's time.

Comment: So sorry. It is a sql query for Oracle/Sql developer.  Yes, I want a header row for teacher id, tfirstname, tlastname, studentid, sfirstname, slastname, studentid, sfirstname, slastname and so on.

Comment: The second table is not what I typed in.  I want one row with one teacher and all of her students across in columns.  This is hard to put in words.